# ListView.builder (even Expanded) doesn't work in a column

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-listview

I am trying to create a popup that shows a list of selected food with ListView.builder, but it throws `RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPhysicalShape#8740e relayoutBoundary=up4`and 'hasSize' error.
I always have problems with ListView.builder and other builders like GridView while I'm putting them as a child into Column, but I always managed to solve it by simply adding Expanded with flex to every child in it.

**What I tried:**
Expanded and flex to every child (also tried only to ListView.builder and then only to Column) - 3/3 failed
Changing Expanded to Flexible also didn't help.

```
Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
          topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Text(
              'Add extra info about your food',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30.0,
                color: Color(0xFFFF86E45),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 2,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return SubmitFoodRow(
                    foodName: selectedFoodList[index],
                  );
                },
              ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

**Hard coding height and width into Container (parent of Column) doesn't help**

```
Container(
      height: 400,
      width: 400,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
          topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              'Add extra info about your food',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30.0,
                color: Color(0xFFFF86E45),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 2,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return SubmitFoodRow(
                    foodName: selectedFoodList[index],
                  );
                },
              ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Adding shrinkWrap or deleting it also doesn't help me.

**Here is how my onPressed function looks like that calls it.**

```
onPressed: ingredientsSelected.isEmpty? null : () {
          showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            // makes it to sit right above keyboard
            isScrollControlled: true,
            builder: (context) => Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
              child: AddFoodPopup(selectedFoodList: ingredientsSelected),
            ),
          );
        },
```

This is project for Mobile App Competition and it is basically finished, but this single (propably the easiest one) error doesn't let me finish it.

Comment: Your code is working when I test. Is any widget wrap above your code, "Container"?. If yes, please provide complete widget tree (code).

Comment: Your code work perfectly.
i'm testing that with Container instead of SubmitFoodRow()

Comment: Thanks for help, I was trying everything thinking ListView was a problem, but SubmitFoodRow() was causing the bug. Should've tested that in a first place, I really appreciate your help.